# rand() для переменных

Tags: c++, переменные, случайные-числа

Можно ли создать несколько переменных и при помощи функции rand() из этих переменных выбрать случайным образом одну?

Comment: Вы можете создать массив из, скажем, пяти элементов и случайно выбрать индекс - от одного до пяти. Так пойдет?

Comment: просто хочу создать игру(с оформлением). И когда выпадало случайное число(если от 1 до 7 то выпало 7) и параллельно создав переменную типа string seven со значением текста (в виде семерки) оно выводило текст переменной seven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a, b, c;

int& x = (rand() > 3000) ? a : (rand() < 2000) ? b : c;
```

Устроит?

Это если вам нужна именно переменная - с возможностью записи и т.д. Если ее значение - и того проще,

```
int x = (rand() > 3000) ? a : (rand() < 2000) ? b : c;
```

Естественно, `rand()` нужно использовать с умом; тут я привел просто для примера...

Это все имеет смысл, когда у вас уже есть переменные, из которых нужно делать выбор. Если вы сами их создаете... конечно, можно работать с массивом, вектором и т.д., но есть у меня подозрение, что это вопрос о том, какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей. Вам точно нужны именно переменные и выбор одной из них?

Comment: да я еще сам думаю что мне нужно. я запутался немного.

Comment: ну если я создам допустим 3 переменные типа string со значениями которые мне нужно будет вывести на экран. и мне нужно случайным образом выбрать одну из трех. вот в таком случае как мне быть?

Comment: Значения могут быть сгенерированные, могут - просто литералы. В последнем случае вам даже переменная не нужна :) - `std::cout << ((rand()%3) ? (rand()%2) ? "First" : "Second" : "Third") << std::endl;`

Comment: 1. Дважды вызывать rand неправильно. 2. Вероятности странные.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да это как пример, в комментарии расписывать код всерьез и подробно, с переменными... :(

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать через массив:

```
std::vector<int> v(5, 0);

// устанавливаем значения в массиве

int value = v.at(rand() % 5);
```

Такой способ позволяет оформить все кратко, если предполагается большое кол-во переменных.

Comment: Лучше сделать массив указателей на переменные, если предполагается их изменение.

Comment: `rand()%5` может [не с одинаковой вероятностью индексы возвращать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/4279)

Comment: @Constructor массив указателей на переменные? но зачем? vector/array покроет 99% потребностей в  данном случае.

Comment: @KoVadim Для оставшегося 1%, очевидно.

Comment: Приведите такой пример пожалуйста.

Comment: @KoVadim Пусть есть некоторое множество объектов и для данной операции (выбор случайного объекта с целью издевательств над ним) выбирается его подмножество. Копировать (или перемещать) объекты подмножества в вектор — несколько сомнительное решение.

Comment: В данном случае лучше shared_ptr. Или просто массив индексов.